# Turn Windows XP machine into a router?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, networking, software-rec, router

I have an older Windows XP SP3 machine sitting around, that has both wired and wireless capabilities, and I would like to turn it into a router that broadcasts a wireless network.

*I know* that this can be done in Windows 7 with [Virtual Router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) or [Connectify](http://connectify.me/).  But I'm looking for a solution for Windows XP.

The question: is this possible?  If so, how can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, however due to the insecure and unstable nature of Windows XP, especially related to networking capabilities, it would be inadvisable.

I would recommend alternatively that you install Ubuntu 10.04 or another Linux distribution on that machine to perform the task. In Ubuntu at least (probably other linux disros as well, there is a program called radvd that will operate as a Router Advertisement Daemon. Besides that there are numerous other possibilities - with much greater / easier control.

Comment: can you advise on how I could do this in Ubuntu or another Linux flavor?

Comment: My advice would be to hit up Google, querying for "radvd" or its variants, and "linux wireless router". Superuser / Serverfault may even have some results already. :)